# How to properly use ng-class in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

How do I properly set `ng-class` conditionals? I have tried everything I see on the internet but can't seem to find the answer.

**This is my code:**

```html
<tr ng-class="byitem.Count != byitem.orderedcount ? error : success" 
    ng-repeat="byitem in weekdata">
```

Basically, all I want is whenever `byitem.count` and `byitem.orderedcount` are not the same then the `class` will be `error` otherwise `success`.

But what I am getting is that even if the `count` and `orderedcount` are the same it still gets the error class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you expect. I added some dummy data to show better how it could work. You were very close, the class names required to be strings and not variables, hence the ' ' marks around them.

```js
let weekdata = [
  {"Count": 1, "text": "something", "orderedcount": 2},
  {"Count": 6, "text": "something else", "orderedcount": 6},
  {"Count": 5, "text": "something 3", "orderedcount": 2},
  {"Count": 2, "text": "something test", "orderedcount": 2},
];

let app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('my', function() {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.weekdata = weekdata
      
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.error{
  background-color:red;
}

.success{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <table my>
    <tr ng-class="byitem.Count != byitem.orderedcount ? 'error' : 'success'" ng-repeat="byitem in weekdata">
      <td>
          {{byitem.text}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: i'll try this one out, hope it will work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

just make `css class` in your `.css file`. for example:

```
.myClass{
  background: blue;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

and then your html tag use ng-class as:

```
<div ng-class="{myClass:true}"><div>
```

here you can put your conditional statement as eg  `a == 1` according to your requirement
instead of using `boolean true` as I did in my sample.

Comment: this is very basic in terms of angularjs. if this helps you out, an upvote to my answer is expected as well.